# Camera moving down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on Unity and I have already set how to smoothly move up camera when player get on higher position. But if player is on position which is below on camera, then you lost " life ". I need a way to show score and highscore but on way that when you lost " life ", camera is moving down to the score/highscore, play again button and something like that.

For better explanation you can see how look like lost " life " on Doodle Jump game.

This is my code which I used to move camera higher during game.

```
void Update()
{
    playerHeightY = player.position.y;

    float currentCameraHeight = transform.position.y;
    float newHeightOfCamera = Mathf.Lerp(currentCameraHeight, playerHeightY, Time.deltaTime * 100f);

    if (playerHeightY > currentCameraHeight)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, newHeightOfCamera, transform.position.z);
    }

    else
    {
        if (playerHeightY < (currentCameraHeight - 5f))
        {
            OnGUI2D.O2G.CheckHighScore();
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene1");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks and all best

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity3d how to change GUI text in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29167172/unity3d-how-to-change-gui-text-in-code)

Comment: simply use Unity's UI to display anything like that. full video tutorials .. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui

Comment: No, https://youtu.be/wjofzwaC_Oo?t=18m30s , did you catch how he lost life and how camera move? I need that move ;)